# I think I have a permissions problem on an EE site - no Extensions will be installed - they remain "Disabled"

Tags: extension, permissions

I have set all permissions to 777 on all folders and files specified by this article: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

I uploaded a new Extension to the new site. It currently says "Disabled", so I click to Enable. It gives me the option to Install a Module and an Extension, I choose to install both.

The page reloads - and the extension remains disabled.

I have tried making the /system/expressionengine/third_party/extension_name/ folder 777 (and all subfiles) but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do other extensions disable/enable? Is it just this one that's the problem?

Comment: Try clicking Enable again and look for the extension name in the exp_extensions table. Does the 'enabled' column change from 'y' to 'n'?

Comment: @DerekHogue yes - others enable/disable.

Comment: @nageeb - interesting - the 'enabled' column doesn't change. However, after installing and changing the column manually, it now works! Any ideas, or will this be a problem in the future?

Comment: Sounds like the extension hasn't implemented the installation function correctly.